# Adding row to DataGrid following previous values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

So I have a list of "Programs" and I want to make it so when I press a button a new row of "Programs" is added to my DataGrid but I've have problem which I cant fix when I add a new row the number of programs start from zero I want it to continue from the last number.

**Here is how the row is added:**

```
private void Add_download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++)
    {
        PL.List_Programs.Add(UpdateList(a));
    }
}

private Programs UpdateList(int a)
{
    Programs P = new Programs();

    //Add a way to get the number of currently downloading programs (e.g.: ProgramID + a)
    int aAsIDNum = PL.ProgramList().IndexOf();

    //Both of these are used to toghter because I cant make a decimal random generator
    double RndSizeGen = new Random().Next(10, 50);
    int RndSizeGen1 = new Random().Next(1, 9);

    //Generates a random number to be used as the progress precent
    int RndProgressGen = new Random().Next(10, 80);

    Programs _programs = new Programs
    {
        ProgramID = a,
        Name = $"Program{a}",
        Size = Convert.ToDouble($"{RndSizeGen}.{RndSizeGen1}"),
        Progress = RndProgressGen
    };

    //Returns the updated list of programs 
    return _programs;
}
```

**Here is the List of "Programs:**

```
public ObservableCollection<Programs> List_Programs {get; set;}

public ObservableCollection<Programs> ProgramList()
{

    List_Programs = new ObservableCollection<Programs>
    {
        new Programs { _programid = 1, _name = "Program0", _size = 5.8, _progress = 100 },
        new Programs { _programid = 2, _name = "Program1", _size = 7.1, _progress = 36 },
        new Programs { _programid = 3, _name = "Program2", _size = 1.4, _progress = 44 },
        new Programs { _programid = 4, _name = "Program3", _size = 6.5, _progress = 100 },
        new Programs { _programid = 5, _name = "Program4", _size = 2.5, _progress = 89 },
        new Programs { _programid = 6, _name = "Program5", _size = 9.6, _progress = 68 },
        new Programs { _programid = 7, _name = "Program6", _size = 5.3, _progress = 90 },
        new Programs { _programid = 8, _name = "Program7", _size = 2.2, _progress = 100 },
        new Programs { _programid = 9, _name = "Program8", _size = 83.7, _progress = 18 }
    };

    return List_Programs;
}
```

**And here are the variables I used:**

```
public class Programs : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnProperyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }

    public int _programid;
    public int ProgramID
    {
        get { return _programid; }
        set
        {
            _programid = value;
            OnProperyChanged(nameof(ProgramID));
        }
    }

    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnProperyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public double _size;
    public double Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set
        {
            _size = value;
            OnProperyChanged(nameof(Size));
        }
    }

    public  double _progress;
    public double Progress
    {
        get { return _progress; }
        set
        {
            _progress = value;
            OnProperyChanged(nameof(Progress));
        }
    }

    public ICollectionView ProgramsView { get; set; }
}
```

**DataGrid/Xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG_List" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="true"
          ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="3">
</DataGrid >
```

Image For reference:
[image: Image for Reference]

Tell me if anything is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++)
{
    PL.List_Programs.Add(UpdateList(a));
}
```

this lines mean that you always create a new item with `0` id. (`for` loop starts from 0 and performs 1 iteration)

if items are not removed from list, you can pass List.Count value as new id:

```
PL.List_Programs.Add(UpdateList(PL.List_Programs.Count))
```

if changes are possible, find max id and use next number:

```
PL.List_Programs.Add(UpdateList(PL.List_Programs.Max(p=>p.ProgramID)+1))
```

Comment: I am kind of happy and sad at the same because I was on this problem for a week and a half and you've answered it in like 2 minutes. Thank you very much anyways

Answer (score 0):

Increase the value of a each time the `Add_download_Click` event handler is invoked:

```
private void Add_download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int a = 10;
    if (PL.List_Programs.Count > 0)
    {
        a = PL.List_Programs[PL.List_Programs.Count - 1].ProgramID + 1;
    }
    PL.List_Programs.Add(UpdateList(a));
}
```